# How to display custom fields in QuickSearch results (RequestTracker)?

Tags: perl, request, tracker, ticket-system, rt

If I click one of the links in the QuickSearch Box inside the main dashboard it lists all tickets correctly, the problem is that I want all my custom fields to be displayed in the quickSearch results.

I already tried setting $DefaultSearchResultFormat in the config file, but it will show the same custom fields for all searches. I have different custom fields in every queue. Is there a way to set a defaultSearchResultFormat for each queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read everywhere and RT doesn't provide a way to do that for every queue. I solved by saving some searches and adding a new dashboard with those links.